# how to debug effectively in visual studio 2017?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I currently do an apprenticeship as an software dev. I'm in my second year now and I'm still a little bit struggling with effectivly debugging.

I couldn't find any topic here on StackOverflow which could give me some advice about clean debugging.

So here is my question:

Does anybody of you got any tips and tricks in debugging? are there any "golden rules" that I need to get better program flow with debugging?

I would be very thankful if you could help me!

Comment: Shortcuts, that is all you need.

Comment: What specific problem do you have with using the debugger - do you know the basics i.e. setting breakpoints, starting the application in debug mode, inspecting variable values etc

Comment: @FCin what do you mean exactly? Just the standard commands like F5, F10, F11 etc.?

Comment: @D.Jahn Yup....

Comment: See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-windows

Comment: @auburg i think it starts with setting breakpoints. i usually set them at a specific point in my code where i think that there is the major error. than i just jump through my code step by step. my problem is that i dont really see the issue or cant find it fast enough...

Comment: thanks alot! will print it out.

Comment: @D.Jahn I think being able to debug effectively comes through experience and being able to take advantage of debugger features outlined in the link i posted

Comment: Debuggibg mean finding bug. From code, read it first understand as much as possible, try to figure out bug from it. Make breaking point in code block which you think have a issue. In VS, know shortcuts, see the watch (can chance debug value), call stacks, move the cursor back and forth to re-run code block. That’s all I think most effectively way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to debug effectively in visual studio 2017?

There is no standard answer for this question. As we know [Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/):

> **The Visual Studio debugger helps you observe the run-time behavior of
>   your program and find problems.** With the debugger, you can break
>   execution of your program to examine your code, examine and edit
>   variables, view registers, see the instructions created from your
>   source code, and view the memory space used by your application.

**There are no tips and tricks here that apply to all questions/issues. A mixture of patience, experience, intuition and good practice is needed.**

Similarly, if you are familiar with the debugger, this will help you improve the efficiency of your debugging.

There is a very good [article about Debugging tips](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/debugging.html):

> Answering questions on the newsgroups, I've noticed that several
>   developers seem to find debugging very difficult - not the mechanics
>   of it, so much as knowing the right place to start. This is not to say
>   that they are lazy or stupid - **just that debugging is an art unto
>   itself** (arguably more so than writing code in the first place - it
>   certainly involves more intuition in my view), and that a few pointers
>   could be useful.
>
> Making use of the techniques discussed on this page won't make you an
>   ace bug-finder in itself - a mixture of patience, experience,
>   intuition and good practice is needed - but my hope is that it can get
>   you started along the right path. Note that although the page title is
>   "Debugging", a lot of the time you may well not need to step through
>   your code in a debugger in order to fix your code. If I'm trying to
>   find a problem in my own code, without external dependencies such as
>   other whole systems being involved, I usually regard it as a failure
>   on my part if I need to use the debugger. It indicates that my code
>   isn't clear enough and my unit tests aren't robust enough.

And [some Debugging Tips and Tricks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/05/22/debugging-tips-and-tricks/), you can check it, if you are interested in.

Hope this helps.